# Docker container not accessible in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container based on node:10-alpine, it was working fine as individual container, but not in docker-compose. Even I exposed the port and set the network_mode, I couldn't visit it from `http://localhost:4000`

If I don't include `network_mode`, the nodejs server will be accessible on port 4000, but I will not have access to the other image's api.

It was working perfectly on ubuntu, but somehow not working on mac (which runs against docker's goal).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    network_mode: host
  agebox:
    image: "another_image"
    ports:
      - "9000:8080"
```

I've tried to erase and rebuild everything multiple times, but still shows "The site can not be reached". Any suggestion on how to best resolve this issue?

Comment: Those two containers should be within common network that is created implicitly by default. Remove network_mode, because it is redundant. How do you reference the API of the service that is in agebox container? If you are referencing it as localhost:9000 this won't work because you need to use the artificial dns names that docker network provides for the services. Simply put, if you want to access api that is inside agebox container you would make for example http GET request under agebox:8080/something. I guess this might be a reason, try that.

Comment: `docker logs $your_container` to see if any issue.

Comment: By `http://localshot:4000` you meant `http://localhost:4000` ?